# Node.js Cluster Example

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

Can someone do an code example for me using node.js natives cluster?

Lets say I have this code and want each 'X' to be balanced between my cores, how would I do that?

```
var y = {};
var i = 0;
var X = require('x.js');

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

console.log("client connected sucessfully");

    ws.on('message', function(obj) {
        for(var a = 0; a < 100; a++){
            y[i] = new X();
            i++;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good example on the node cluster [documentation page](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). In short, you want to use `cluster.fork()` to create a new worker. The worker will execute the same code that master does, so your example would become something like this:

```
var y = {};
var i = 0;
var X = require('x.js');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (var worker_num = 0; worker_num < 10; worker_num++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log("client connected sucessfully");
      ws.on('message', function(obj) {
        for(var a = 0; a < 100; a++){
          y[i] = new X();
          i++;
        }
     });
  });
}
```

However in reality you would need way more than that. You'd want features like automatic worker restarts, heartbeats, etc etc, so writing good cluster managing code is a big task by itself. I suggest using some ready solution [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) or [service-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-runner)

Comment: oh I haven't mentioned it, the websocket should not be splitted. So there should only be one websocket server.